# PHP - How can i call a POST with a variable inside?

Tags: php

I have a POST called

```
name='update_name".$id."'
```

This ID comes from an Foreach.

And i dont know how to call this POST because there is an variable inside.

I'm using MVC, i created the function inside the model, and i'm calling the function inside view:

But i dont know how to call the variable.

I want my script to read the name like this:

```
$variable = $_POST['update_name1'];
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear? Are you talking about setting the value in a form to be POSTed or reading it from a POST REQUEST? Maybe show some code snippets so we can understand and help you?

Comment: i'm talking about setting the value in a form to be posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way as setting the tame of your input

```
$variable = $_POST['update_name'.$i];
```

Bud i recomend you to use name attribute as array

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="update_name[]" />
<input type="text" name="update_name[]" />
```

PHP

```
<?
   foreach ($_POST[update_name] as $item){
      // $item `s are now values from input       
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="update_name<?php echo $id; ?>" value="">
```

And you can read it as:

```
$variable = $_POST['update_name'.$i];
```